# Need run twice Node.removeChild() for node removed

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to remove the first `li` node but I have to run `deleteNode();` twice for the node be removed.

I need to remove the `li` tag and the `img` tag inside...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  deleteNode();
  deleteNode();
}


function deleteNode() {
  var node;
  node = document.getElementById("sliders");
  node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="jsSlider">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <ul id="sliders">
        <li>
          <img src="img/sample-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="img/sample-2.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="img/sample-3.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="prueba"></div>
</body>
```

This is pure javascript I cannot use jQuery or any other js framwork.
How can I remove the `li` tag while only running `Node.removeChild()` one time?

Comment: `node.removeChild(node.children[0]);`

Comment: @SampathLiyanage—according to [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children#Browser_compatibility), *children* has limited support.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `firstElementChild` instead because `firstChild` is returning text:

```
window.onload=deleteNode();

function deleteNode() {
  var node;
  node = document.getElementById("sliders");
  node.removeChild(node.firstElementChild);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5apt39yd/)

Comment: According to [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.firstElementChild), support for *firstElementChild* is limited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the first LI child of *#sliders*, then the following will work in all browsers:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('sliders');
ul.removeChild(ul.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]);
```

In more modern browsers (probably even IE8):

```
var firstLi = document.querySelector('#sliders li');
firstLi.parentNode.removeChild(firstLi);
```

The above methods precisely target the first LI, they don't depend on a particular DOM structure. To use your original code, and ensure that the LI is the first child, change the markup to:

```
  <ul id="sliders"><li>
        <img src="img/sample-1.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
```

Now there is no text node between the UL and LI.

Answer (score 0):

this is becuase text is are also considired node  in browers

use a function to check type of node

```
function getFirstchild( elem ) {
     do {
         elem = elem.firstChild;
        } 
     while ( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 );
 return elem;
  }
```

**Working demo with one time call:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  deleteNode();

}

    function getFirstchild( elem ) {
     do {
         elem = elem.firstChild;
        } 
     while ( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 );
 return elem;
  }
 
function deleteNode() {
  var node;
  node = document.getElementById("sliders");
  node.removeChild(getFirstchild(node));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="jsSlider">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <ul id="sliders"><li>
          <img src="img/sample-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </li><li>
          <img src="img/sample-2.jpg" alt="" />
        </li><li>
          <img src="img/sample-3.jpg" alt="" />
        </li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="prueba"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function deleteNode() {
    var node;
    node = document.getElementById("sliders");
    node.removeChild(node.childNodes[1]);
    }
```

This will work as your firstchild is not **li** but the **text**

Comment: Unless there are zero or two, or more text nodes between the UL and LI. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `children` as well:

```
window.onload=deleteNode();

function deleteNode() {
  var node;
  node = document.getElementById("sliders");
  node.removeChild(node.children[0]);
}
```

img is an element of the #sliders div, therefore `.children`, or even `.firstElementChild` are used to to access the img; a child element.

However, `.childNodes` counts any type of property of #sliders div, meaning even whitespaces between the li tags are counted... which is the source of your problem.

**EDIT

It seems that `.children` and `.firstElementChild` has limited support for IE and Safari, if this is an issue, try the following :

```
window.onload=deleteNode();

function deleteNode() {
  var node;
  var elem;
  node = document.getElementById("sliders");
  for (elem = node.firstChild;
         elem;
         elem = elem.nextSibling
        ) {

        if (elem.nodeType == 1) { // 1 == Element
            node.removeChild(elem);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The for loop iterates through the children and removes the first occurrence of a child that is an element. Here's a fiddle to demonstrate...http://jsfiddle.net/5apt39yd/3/

Comment: As with *children*, *firstElementChild* has limited support (see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.firstElementChild#Browser_compatibility)).

Comment: You're right, in IE for example, it seems that comment nodes are counted as element nodes, which may or may not be a significant issue for OP